# Is there a way to assign coordinates of a react component to match event.screenX, and event.screenY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I thought this would work but it seems to be more complicated than I thought. I'm trying to program an event in my React app where a simple component appears where I click (event.screenX, event.screenY). Here's what I've got so far:-

The block below is from my stateful component which handles clicking and the window.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      'objects': []
   }

   ClickHandler(event) {
      let tempObjects = this.state.objects;
      tempObjects.push({
         'xCoord': event.screenX,
         'yCoord': event.screenY
      });
      this.setState({
         'objects': tempObjects
      });
   }

   ComponentDidUpdate() {
      this.divContent = this.state.objects.map( obj => {
         //Coordinates passed in as props and assigned in style
         <Object xCoord={obj.xCoord} yCoord={obj.yCoord}/>
      });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div onClick={ClickHandler}>
            {this.divContent}
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

And this is the component of the object that I'm trying to get to appear

```
Object(props) {
   let objCoordinates= {
      'top': props.yCoord,
      'left': props.xCoord
   };
   return <div style={objCoordinates}></div>;
}
```

The issue is that the resulting React App displays the objects on the screen when clicked, but the coordinates never match the mouse position, and are often out of the page boundaries where they can't be seen.

Has anybody else come across this issue before, and if so how were you able to resolve it?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Try `let tempObjects = this.state.objects.slice();`

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to investigate this without a proper playground with the code. But be mindful of doing things like this:

```
 let tempObjects = this.state.objects;
      tempObjects.push({
         'xCoord': event.screenX,
         'yCoord': event.screenY
      });
```

When you push like this you're actually pushing into the state array through the reference which you should never do.

You're better of doing it like this:

```
 let tempObjects = [...this.state.objects];
      tempObjects.push({
         'xCoord': event.screenX,
         'yCoord': event.screenY
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've amended my code to reflect what's above.